How to show multiple widget option in Home screen quick action?
In iOS 18 beta, I’ve noticed that when you long press on an app icon, native apps now display a widget option in the context menu. When you click on the widget option, the app icon seamlessly transforms into a widget directly on the home screen.
This is a great feature, and I’m interested in enabling it for my own apps. Could anyone provide guidance on how to implement this feature or point me to the relevant documentation?
Not working when multiple widgets are supplied to widgetBundle.

Short answer
If you already have at-least one widget implemented, then iOS18 will automatically show it for the users.
The issue
from your comment

"Not working when multiple widgets are supplied to widgetBundle."

It looks like, you assumed that the popup allows user to cycle between different widgets in WidgetBundle, which is causing confusion.
How it works
To make it easy to understand we can break it down into 2 parts:

WidgetBundle - "A container used to expose multiple widgets from a single widget extension."
Widget - "The configuration and content of a widget to display on the Home screen or in Notification Center."

Now, a single Widget(home screen) has 3 sizes: .systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge which are part of WidgetFamily. iOS18 allows user to resize within them on the home screen.

I hope this solves your doubt.
